# Using algebra to obtain trigonometric inequalities

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I found this in a text book. We are asked to show $\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(z)\le3/2$, when $x+y+z=\pi$. Textbook's explanation has used the completing square method as follows:$$1-2\left(\sin\frac{z}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos\frac{x-y}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}\cos^2\frac{x-y}{2}\le1+\frac{1}{2}\cos^2\frac{x-y}{2}\le3/2$$

The problem I have is how do you exactly know it is maximum when the middle term goes to zero? It is okay when the last term is a constant. But, here when taking middle term to zero, the last term also changes. How do you explain the reasoning used to obtain the inequality? Can you obtain such an inequality if the final result is not given?

Comment: The middle term is the subtraction of a non-negative value (since the square of any real value is always non-negative), so any non-zero value of the middle term will result in a smaller expression result than if the middle term is $0$.

Comment: It leads us to correct answer, but, when middle term goes to zero, last term also changes. With this fact, is your reasoning logical?

Comment: Once you have written the inequality you have proved what was to be proved. Why do you need to find the maximum? I don't see how we can "explain the reasoning used to solve the problem" when you have told us neither the problem nor the reasoning.

Comment: I have edited some sections. My problem here is, when taking middle term to zero the last term may also decrease. So can we exactly know there is a maximum, when the middle term goes to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is whether or not the upper bound $\frac32$ of $\cos x + \cos y + \cos z$ (given $x+y+z = \pi$) is attained. This is easy to check: $x = y = z = \frac{\pi}{3}$ satisfies the requirements.

In general, to see if an upper bound is attained, you should see what happens when equality holds everywhere. Doing this will force certain conditions on the variables (in our case, $x,y,z$.)